# piece of jquery code is not working in angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have a directive that has several inputs inside of it, and i have an specific input that i need to execute a function when enter is pressed.

This is the input that i need to execute a function.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cep" id="inputcep">
```

And i have a jquery function that uses a mask plugin and a keypress listener that prevents the default action of the enter key and executes the function. My problem is that the keypress is not being called, but the mask is being applied :/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#inputcep')
              .keypress(function(ev){
                  console.log(ev);
                  if(ev.keyCode == 13){
                       ev.preventDefault();
                       scope.searchCep(scope.cep);
                   }
            })
            .mask('00000-000');
});
```

Comment: you should write you code inside you directive, your link function will look like `element.on('keypress', function(event){})`

Answer (score 3):

Use angular instead of jQuery :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress

Answer (score 0):

Do create you custom directive as below.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('customDir', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            element.keypress(function(ev) {
                console.log(ev);
                if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    scope.searchCep(scope.cep);
                }
            }).mask('00000-000');
        });
    };
});
```